# How to work with script tags using page-object gem and ruby

Tags: ruby, page-object-gem

With watir I am able to grab the html for a specific script tag

```
scripts = @browser.scripts
index = scripts.find_index {|s| s.html.include? 'mytest.string'}
icode = scripts[index].html
etc.
```

The string I am looking for is unique and part of a longer string. I need to verify the longer string is correct. Right now I am doing it as described above but would prefer to do it the page object way if possible. I am using page-object gem and ruby for the rest of my code. Would like to do the same with this script tag if possible. If not I will stick with the watir way.

As always your help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I assume your html has something like:

```
<html>
  <body>
    <script>other random script</script>
    <script>some stuff mytest.string some other stuff</script>
    <script>another random script</script>
  </body>
</html>
```

To get script elements with the page-object-gem, you can use the generic `element` accessor. You could then define your page object as:

```
class MyPage
  include PageObject

  element(:test_script, :script, :xpath => '//script[contains(text(), "mytest.string")]')
end
```

Here, I have used the :xpath locator to locate the script by its text. Using :xpath is not usually the suggested choice, however I could not find another solution. You cannot use the :text locator since Watir only returns the visible text, which is nothing for a script element. The :xpath locator allows you to bypass that constraint.

With this page defined, you can get the html of the script element as follows:

```
page = MyPage.new(browser)
page.test_script_element.html
#=> "<script>some stuff mytest.string some other stuff</script>"
```

Comment: Thanks Justin. I will give this a try. Was hoping to avoid xpath but if it is the only way then I will use that.